# Read in a string from file line per line and just the first word

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I got this Code from [here](https://www.c-plusplus.net/forum/286828).

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <string> 
#include <limits> // numeric_limits 

void print_line( const std::string& filename, int lnNo ) 
{ 
    using namespace std; 
    ifstream file( filename.c_str() ); 
    if( !file.is_open() ) 
    { 
        cerr << "Fehler beim Oeffnen der Datei " << filename << endl; 
        return 0; 
    } 
    for( ; lnNo > 1; --lnNo ) 
        file.ignore( numeric_limits< streamsize >::max(), '\n' ); 
    string line; 
    if( !getline( file, line ) ) 
    { 
        cerr << "Fehler beim Lesen aus der Datei " << filename << endl; 
        return 0; 
    } 
    cout << line << endl; 
} 

int main () 
{ 
    using namespace std; 
    for( int lnNo; cin >> lnNo; ) 
        print_line( "input.txt", lnNo ); 
    return 0; 
}
```

This reads in a whole line specified by `lnNo`. What do I have to change when I just want to read in the first word per line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to extract a single "word" from a string. You could find the space and get a substring, or you could put the string in an input string stream and read using the normal input operator, you could use regular expressions to extract the first "word", and probably some more. With the help of [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) you can experiment and see what you think is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to your response, Joachim Pileborg, I could answer my question by myself. I added the two lines to the end of `print_line`:

```
int strpos = line.find(" ");
string input = line.substr(0, strpos);
cout << input << endl;
```